# Difference between getRawBody() and getBody() methods of Zend_Http_Response?

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, response

Hi wondring whats the difference between $response->getBody() and $response->getRawBody();

```
$this->_client->setUri('http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en');
        try {
            $response = $this->_client->request();
        }catch(Zend_Http_Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'Zend http Client Failed';
        }
        echo get_class($response);
        if($response->isSuccessful())
        {
           $response->getBody();
           $response->getRawBody();

        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getRawBody()` returns the body of the http response as is.

`getBody()` adjust for certain headers i.e. decompresses content sent with gzip or deflate content-encoding headers. Or the chunked transfer-encoding header.

The simplest way figure these questions out in to simply look at the code. Also a great learning experience. Code is edited for brevity.

```
public function getRawBody()
{
    return $this->body;
}

public function getBody()
{
    $body = '';

    // Decode the body if it was transfer-encoded
    switch (strtolower($this->getHeader('transfer-encoding'))) {
        case 'chunked':
            // Handle chunked body
            break;
        // No transfer encoding, or unknown encoding extension:
        default:
            // return body as is
            break;
    }

    // Decode any content-encoding (gzip or deflate) if needed
    switch (strtolower($this->getHeader('content-encoding'))) { 
        case 'gzip':
             // Handle gzip encoding
            break;
        case 'deflate':
            // Handle deflate encoding
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return $body;
}
```

Comment: I now understand the difference thanks for taking time to answer ,

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP body may be encoded in various ways.
For example, it may be split in different chunks, each one preceded with the chunk size, or gzipped:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

getBody() will return a processed HTTP body, according to it's encoding type.
getRawBody will return the HTTP body as is.